# Renames numbered files using names from list in other file

Tags: shell, ubuntu, filenames

I have a folder where there are books and I have a file with the real name of each file. I renamed them in a way that I can easily see if they are ordered, say "00.pdf", "01.pdf" and so on.

I want to know if there is a way, using the shell, to match each of the lines of the file, say "names", with each file. Actually, match the line `i` of the file with the book in the positión `i` in sort order.

```
<name-of-the-book-in-the-1-line>  ->  <book-in-the-1-position>
<name-of-the-book-in-the-2-line>  ->  <book-in-the-2-position>
.
.
.
<name-of-the-book-in-the-i-line>  ->  <book-in-the-i-position> 
.
.
.
```

I'm doing this in Windows, using Total Commander, but I want to do it in Ubuntu, so I don't have to reboot.

I know about `mv` and `rename`, but I'm not as good as I want with regular expressions...

Comment: How do you know which file corresponds to which full name? Is that number unique?

Comment: I've opened the files in ascending order (00, 01, ..., N), thought a name, and wrote it in the file "names"

Comment: How does *name-book-01.pdf* become *01.pdf*, while *name-book-99.pdf* becomes *00.pdf*? What happens with *name-book-100.pdf*?

Comment: It is still not clear to me. There has to be a way to know which full name corresponds to which short name, and "thought a name" doesn't tell me that. Plus the inconsistency @KenWhite points out.

Comment: My bad. Files in the directory are named like "number.pdf", for example "13.pdf". In a text file, line 14, is the name that I want for that file, wich is "Pro Git, 2nd Ed. [Scott CHACON - Ben STRAUB].pdf".
The names starts from "00.pdf", not from "01.pdf", but I think that is easy fixed with a command line.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

renamer.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls -v |grep -Ev '(renamer.sh|names.txt)'`; do
    read name
    mv "$i" "$name.pdf"
    echo "$i" renamed to "$name.pdf"
done < names.txt
```

names.txt: (line count must be the exact equal to numbered files count)

```
name of first book
second-great-book
...
```

explanation:

- `ls -v` returns naturally sorted file list
- grep excludes this script name and input file to not be renamed
- we cycle through found file names, read value from file and rename the target files by this value

For testing purposes, you can comment out the `mv` command:

```
#mv "$i" "$name"
```

And now, simply run the script:

```
bash renamer.sh
```

Comment: a good debugging/safety technique is to use `echo "$i" "$name.pdf"` in the script. Look at that output, and confirm the script is working as needed .... then remove the `echo` and all files will be renamed when O.P. reruns. Good luck to all.

Comment: This is exactly the program that I needed. Thank you!

Comment: In the file I wrote the names with the extension, so this works. But it's a good point

Comment: Ok, so simply remove `.pdf` extension from the script and that's it. Enjoy it and rather make backup before the action ;)

Answer (score 1):

This loops through `names.txt`, creates a filename based on a counter (padding to two digits with `printf`, assigning to a variable using `-v`), then renames using `mv`. `((++i))` increases the counter for the next filename.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf -v fname "%02d.pdf" "$i"
    mv "$fname" "$line"
    ((++i))
done < names.txt
```